# Pipelines in c#

Tags: parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, pipeline

I am writing a server code. The client writes asynchronously to this server. Using System.Net namespace, httplistener is hosted. I want to search for a pattern in the incoming stream. But as the stream is asynchronous how do I append the incoming next stream and carry on searching the pattern? The pattern is the message boundary in MIME part. Sorry for being vague as I am new to this technology. The message boundary can occur in next stream too. How to I parse these conditions?

How can I come to know about the end of input? Should I consider the last message boundary in the stream to be final or is there any end of file indication provided while client server communication.

Comment: The [Dataflow components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the Task Parallel Library already allow the creation of complex pipelines with controlled concurrent execution of the various steps.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Why do you have multiple streams? Also, I don't see what does this have to do with pipelines.

Comment: The client is sending huge chunks of data which is image in between MIME body types. Due to this the existing RAM usage is increased. For this issue I thought the best possible solution is pipelines. Is there any alternative solution?

Comment: To make it simpler to understand the task which I want to accomplish is : 1. Read byte from the stream 
2. Search the byte pattern in the stream 
3. As soon as the first pattern is found I want to write the remaining byte to another buffer until next pattern is hit.
4. Repeat the process until the end of stream is found
How do I accomplish this task?

Comment: Both read and write should happen simultaneously